# ConTeXt: How to align inmargin text so it doesn't go below the text area?

Tags: context

This is for a double sided document I'm designing that has multiple, and some quite long, notes at the margins.

There are some of those notes that are coupled with a text that starts low in the page, and when said notes have a quite long text, it 'overflows' the text area, like in this minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\showframe
\definemargindata[notemargin][ininner][style=small]

\starttext
\input knuth\par
\notemargin{Some words just to fill text and make a point}\input ward
\stoptext
```

Which produces something like this:

[image: First page of the output of the minimal example. Please take a look at the lower left corner.]

So on those cases I want the text in the notes to be raised up so the bottom of them matches with the bottom of the text area. But for the life of me I can't make it happen. I guess it *should* be something about the `location` parameter in `\setupmargindata` (wiki says it's inherited from `\setupframed`):

```
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\showframe
\definemargindata[notemargin][ininner][style=small,location=<whatever>]

\starttext
\input knuth\par
\notemargin{Some words just to fill text and make a point}\input ward
\stoptext
```

I tried with every single option given in the wiki, but all of them make the text in the margin to disappear. Even letting `location=` does the same thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like your margin note is vertically centered to your last baseline. Have a look at the trick used in the wiki https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes#Footnotes_in_the_margin

Comment: A dirty hack would be to use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511907/context-calculating-remaining-space-on-page-like-testpage to test whether there are few lines left and insert the note in a `\vbox` if so